# Using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am checking for precedence in a string in my function. Is there a way to change my code to incorporate regex -- I am quite unfamiliar with regex, and though I have read some tutorials online, still not getting 'it' too well. So any guidance would really be appreciated.

For example in a string XLYZ, if the char after X is not L or C, the 'violation' statement gets printed. Here's the code below:

```
if (subtnString[cnt]=='X' && cnt+1<subtnString.length){
                if(subtnString[cnt+1]!= 'L' || subtnString[cnt+1]!= 'C'){
                    System.out.println("Violation: X can be subtracted from L and C only");
                    return  false;
                }
            }
```

**Is there a way I can use regex to replace this code?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^X[LC]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if(regexMatcher.find() )  { // it matched!
}
else { // nasty message
     }
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/zL4hX4), see the strings that match.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `X` matches the literal `X`
- `[LC]` is a character class that matches either one `L` or one `C`

---

**Reference**

- [Java Class String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [Using Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Comment: Given these explanations, XLYZ doesn't match the regex.

Comment: Great answer! The only thing I would add is that you should check tou the [Documentation on Strings in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You can browse all the methods it provides for working with strings.

Comment: @zx81 yes, we do match the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

to match texts that **violate** your rule use this regex:

```
X[^LC]
```

see [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG6wW6)

and to match regex that **do not violate** your rule use this:

```
X[LC]
```

see [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yK9iV4)